# Proxy JavaScript через функцию

Tags: javascript, proxy

Я изучаю `Proxy` в JavaScript и пытаюсь сделать `Proxy` для создания массива через `new`.
Я хочу использовать функцию, вместо переменной но у меня не получается.
Я закомментировал мою неработающую функцию, хочу, чтобы эта функция работала также как и const. Не понимаю, почему не происходит тот же самый вывод

```js
//function IndexedArray(args) {
//  return new Proxy(Array, {
//    construct(target, [args]) {
//      return new target(...args);
//    }
//  });
//}

const IndexedArray = new Proxy(Array, {
  construct(target, [args]) {
    return new target(...args);
  }
});

const users = new IndexedArray([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(users);
```

**UPD:**
По советам @Grundy я попробовал сделать `return` этого прокси с оператором `new`, но это не тоже самое, что с `const`.
Вот, результаты:

```js
function IndexedArray(args) {
  let a = new Proxy(Array, {
    construct(target, [args]) {
      return new target(...args);
    }
  });
  console.log('func', new a(args));
  return new a(args);
}

const IndexedArray1 = new Proxy(Array, {
  construct(target, [args]) {
    console.log('const:', new target(...args));
    return new target(...args);
  }
});

const users = new IndexedArray([1, 2, 3]);
const users1 = new IndexedArray1([1, 2, 3]);
console.log('');
const users2 = IndexedArray([1, 2, 3]);
const users3 = IndexedArray1([1, 2, 3]);
```

Comment: не понял, в сниппете сейчас то, что должно работать? Или то что неправильно работает? Какой результат ты ожидаешь?

Comment: @Grundy я хочу, чтобы закоментированная функция работала также, как и const

Comment: _Не понимаю, почему не происходит тот же самый вывод_ - потому что ты применяешь new не к Proxy, а к функции.

Comment: @Grundy из функции возвращается же Proxy

Comment: правильно, верни этот прокси, примени к нему оператор `new` и получишь тот же результат что и с переменной

Comment: @Grundy обновил вопрос

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106163/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Основная ошибка в том, что там где ожидается объект `Proxy` в коде с функцией появляется функция, который этот объект возвращает.

Исходя из этого, чтобы результат был одинаковым - нужно предварительно получить этот объект

```js
function IndexedArray(args) {
  return new Proxy(Array, {
    construct(target, [args]) {
      return new target(...args);
    }
  });
}

const IndexedArray1 = new Proxy(Array, {
  construct(target, [args]) {
    return new target(...args);
  }
});

var IndexedArrayProxy = IndexedArray();

const users = new IndexedArrayProxy([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(users);
const users1 = new IndexedArray1([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(users1);
```

---

Также можно применять и более сложную технику со скобками, чтобы не сохранять отдельной переменной:

```js
function IndexedArray(args) {
  return new Proxy(Array, {
    construct(target, [args]) {
      return new target(...args);
    }
  });
}

const IndexedArray1 = new Proxy(Array, {
  construct(target, [args]) {
    return new target(...args);
  }
});

const users = new(IndexedArray())([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(users);
const users1 = new IndexedArray1([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(users1);
```

---

Во втором примере кода, проблема та же, только теперь функция всегда возвращает результат, который нужен только для оператора `new`.

Для решения можно просто проверить, вызывается ли функция как конструктор или нет и в зависимости от этого

```js
function IndexedArray(args) {
  let a = new Proxy(Array, {
    construct(target, [args]) {
      return new target(...args);
    }
  });

  if (new.target)
    return new a(args);

  return a(args);
}

const IndexedArray1 = new Proxy(Array, {
  construct(target, [args]) {
    return new target(...args);
  }
});

const users = new IndexedArray([1, 2, 3]);
const users1 = new IndexedArray1([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(users, users1)
console.log('');
const users2 = IndexedArray([1, 2, 3]);
const users3 = IndexedArray1([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(users2, users3)
```